# Posting a new Entity with new Child Entity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor-2

My domain model is a Company entity with one or more CompanyAdmin entities.

I realize that for the default model binder to work when posting the form values, the CompanyAdmin entities must have unique names.

When browsing to the page for the first time, there is no data for either the Company or CompanyAdmin. This means, this code doesn't work in the View and hence doesn't display the input text boxes.

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Company.CompanyContacts)
```

So, to make them display I use:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Company.CompanyContacts.ElementAt(0).FirstName)
```

But, now the problem is the model binding doesn't work when POSTing. All the examples I can find are using data that has already been created.

How can I get this to work?

ViewModel

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace ContractorDirect.Models
{
  public class CompanyAdminViewModel
  {
    public Company Company { get; set; }
    public RegisterModel UserReg { get; set; }
  }
}
```

Controller

```
public ViewResult CompanyAdmin(int? id)
    {
        CompanyAdminViewModel cavm = new CompanyAdminViewModel();

        jobTitleRepository = new JobTitleRepository();
        companyContactRepository = new CompanyContactRepository();

        var jobtitles = jobTitleRepository.All;
        ViewBag.JobTitleId = new SelectList(jobtitles, "JobTitleId", "JobName");

        if (id.HasValue)
        {
            cavm.Company = companyRepository.Find((int)id);
            cavm.Company.CompanyContacts = companyContactRepository.All.Where(admin=>admin.IsCompanyAdmin).ToList();
            return View(cavm);
        }

        cavm.Company = new Company();
        cavm.Company.CompanyContacts = new List<CompanyContact>();
        cavm.UserReg = new RegisterModel();
        return View(cavm);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CompanyAdmin(CompanyAdminViewModel cavm)
    {
        JobTitleRepository rep = new JobTitleRepository();
        var jobtitles = rep.All;
        ViewBag.JobTitleId = new SelectList(jobtitles, "JobTitleId", "JobName");

        cavm.UserReg.UserName = cavm.Company.CompanyContacts.ElementAt(0).Email;

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            AccountController account = new AccountController();
            account.Register(cavm.UserReg, "CompanyAdmin");
            companyRepository.InsertOrUpdate(cavm.Company);
            companyRepository.Save();
            return RedirectToAction("CompanyRegistrationConfirmation");
        }
        else
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

VIEW

```
  @model ContractorDirect.Models.CompanyAdminViewModel

  @{
       ViewBag.Title = "CompanyAdmin";
   }

 <h2>Company Admin</h2>

 <table>
 <tr style="vertical-align: top">
    <td>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Company.CompanyName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Company.CompanyName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Company.CompanyName)
        </div>

        <fieldset>
            <legend>Company Administrator</legend>



            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Company.CompanyContacts.ElementAt(0).JobTitleId)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.DropDownList("JobTitleId", string.Empty)
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Company.CompanyContacts.ElementAt(0).FirstName)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Company.CompanyContacts.ElementAt(0).FirstName)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Company.CompanyContacts.ElementAt(0).FirstName)
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Company.CompanyContacts.ElementAt(0).LastName)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Company.CompanyContacts.ElementAt(0).LastName)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Company.CompanyContacts.ElementAt(0).LastName)
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Company.CompanyContacts.ElementAt(0).Email)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Company.CompanyContacts.ElementAt(0).Email)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Company.CompanyContacts.ElementAt(0).Email)
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Company.CompanyContacts.ElementAt(0).Phone)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Company.CompanyContacts.ElementAt(0).Phone)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Company.CompanyContacts.ElementAt(0).Phone)
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserReg.Password)
            </div>

            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserReg.Password)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserReg.Password)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserReg.ConfirmPassword)
            </div>

            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserReg.ConfirmPassword)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserReg.ConfirmPassword)
            </div>

        </fieldset>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Your Question is hard to follow. Please include your full View and Models in your question description.

Comment: I suppose I could use two different Views but I was hoping to find a way to do this is one View.

Comment: Greg, this is better, but also include your company object. This is where most of the activity is happening

Comment: Dave, the Company object is not the issue. Let me try and explain again. How do I post a one-to many data structure so that the default model binding recognizes the child part of the structure ; (Everything with ElementAt(0)  )

Comment: The fix lies with the naming of the child collection entities. So, Element(0) does not render a unique name .. and the modelbinder cant see the values. Phil Haack blogged on it but his is seeding data. I am not. http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx

Answer (score 1):

OK - the problem was in the view

This works

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Company.CompanyContacts[0].FirstName)
```

This does not

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Company.CompanyContacts.ElementAt(0).FirstName)
```

Comment: oic, yeah i didnt understand the(0) reference type